# Trying to retrieve Data from MongoDB using Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

Context: Am not too experienced with TypeScript, as we don't use it at work, am attempting to just build a little portfolio piece for personal exposure.

So to start with this is my code:

```
import { request, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { Neighborhood as NeighborhoodType } from '../interfaces/neighborhood.interface';
import Neighborhood from '../models/neighborhood';

const fetchNeighborhoods = async (request: Request, response: Response): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const neighborhoods: NeighborhoodType[] = await Neighborhood.paginate();
    response.status(200).send(neighborhoods);
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Am attempting to fetch the neighborhoods from the DB, and am receiving the error `Type 'PaginateResult<Neighborhood>' is missing the following properties from type 'Neighborhood[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.` on this line `const neighborhoods: NeighborhoodType[] = await Neighborhood.paginate();`

If I remove the `NeighborhoodType[]` then the method will work fine. The neighborhood interface is literally an object with a string.

```
export interface Neighborhood extends Document {
  name: string,
}
```

Is it an issue with MY code or is it an issue with one of the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encounters this issue:

The problem stems from trying to set the return type. As Mongoose will always return one document, an array of documents or an empty array (unless using `onFail()`) the return type can be inferred so there is no need to add `NeighborhoodType[]`.

The PaginateResult Type is essentially the type of Array if I'm not mistaken and is expecting the Neighborhood type to have all of the array methods which it will not.